# Looping through links via WebDriver

Tags: javascript, selenium, jasmine

I am currently testing a web page via WebDriver I/O. I would like to be able to select a couple of links and "click" them. Currently, I have the following:

```
it('Should click links', function(done) {
  client
    .elements('a').then(function(links) {
      console.log(links);
      console.log('---------');

      for (var i=0; i<links.value.length; i++) {
        client.getAttribute(links.value[i].ELEMENT)
      }

      expect(true).toBe(true);
      done();   
    })
  ;
});
```

When I execute this test, I see the following in the console window:

```
{ state: 'success',
  sessionId: '85d25e09-13d8-475a-81b6-87431d2d8f3c',
  hCode: 1234567890,
  value: 
   [ { ELEMENT: '0' },
     { ELEMENT: '1' },
     { ELEMENT: '2' } ],
  class: 'org.openqa.selenium.remote.Response',
  status: 0 }
---------
{ ELEMENT: '0' }
{ ELEMENT: '1' }
{ ELEMENT: '2' }
```

My question is, how do I "click" the link? When I printed out the link, I was expecting to see an ID, an href, an xpath, or some way to reference the link. But I don't see anything. When I look at the [docs](http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/elements.html), they mention that the elements are returned as WebElement JSON objects. However, I can't seem to find any docs on WebElement.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tell it to click on the element, just like the docs say: http://webdriver.io/api/action/click.html

In your case, the code would be something like:

```
it('Should click links', function(done) {
  client
    .elements('a').then(function(links) {
      console.log(links);
      console.log('---------');

      for (var i=0; i<links.value.length; i++) {
        client.click(links[i])
      }

      expect(true).toBe(true);
      done();   
    })
  ;
});
```

Your code will probably be different, but this should get you started. Now, a couple of quick points:

1) You should avoid having mulitple assertions inside a test. It violates OAPT and can make your tests harder to find when one is failing.

2) You might check out Protractor (http://www.protractortest.org) for E2E testing. It doesn't require Angular and it can make your testing life a lot easier.

Comment: I do agree that you should avoid having multiple assertions inside of a test. Still, if I put the `done()` inside of the `client.click(links.value[i], function(value) { done(); });` it never gets called. Why is that?

Comment: That's a good question and I don't have an answer at the moment.